# decimal? type is not culture specific

Tags: c#, resharper, cultureinfo

I was converting a `decimal` to a `string`, using the following lines of code:

```
decimal a = 0;
a.ToString();
```

and Resharper gave me the following warning: "*Specify string culture explicity*". I guess this makes sense, since some cultures may use a "." (dot) or a "," (comma) as a decimal mark.

However, the following lines of code:

```
decimal? a = 0; //a is now nullable
a.ToString();
```

do not present the same warning. I was wondering if this is a bug in Resharper, or is there something special about a nullable `decimal`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To extend upon Gama Felix's answer, I would assume that this is because `decimal?.ToString()` does not have overloads which would accept a culture. If you don't care about culture specific strings, then you're set.  If you *do* care, then you should check for a value and use `decimal?.Value.ToString()`.

Comment: Just to add that the default `ToString` uses the current thread's `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it happens because `decimal?` is just a alias to `Nulable<decimal>`, so you are calling the `ToString()` method on the nullable class not the decimal type.

Comment: It's `Nullable<T>` which doesn't have any overloads on its `ToString()` method.